# Pyhton3 Code,Class and Methods , why does the method won't return value , though it the code look ok without any problem

Tags: python-3.x, string, class, methods, attributes

i try to build this code see below for the objective and advise why the method "sleep" won't return the value of self.name and the string afterwards if the cat is sleeping.. , the result only gives the second method jumpy.

```
# Objective:create a class cat with the following attributes:
# name , age , sex
# with the following methods: sleep : 
# run only if attribute name is passed
# jumpy : if run function , sex needs to be male

class Cat:
   def __init__(self, name='', age='', sex=''):
      self.name = name
      self.age = age
      self.sex = sex
   def sleep(self):
      if self.name != None:
          return f'{self.name} if sleeping, leave him alone!'
   def jumpy(self):
      if self.sex == "male":
          print("the cat jumping like a maniac!!")
      else:
          print("this cat is lazy Garfield!!")

 Mycat = Cat('miki', 5, 'female')

 Mycat.sleep()
 Mycat.jumpy()

 this cat is lazy garfield!!
```

Comment: you return the string, but never use it. you will either need to `print(Mycat.sleep())` or print from with in it if you want output

Comment: that works now super10x!!